# Buttons not deselecting after reclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

Having a single button selected at a time works as it's supposed to, but when a button is clicked, it won't deselect when it's clicked again.

I feel like the solution to this is very simple but I can't figure it out.

```
  <div id="buttonWrapper">
   <button class="buttonArray"></button>
   <button class="buttonArray"></button>
   <button class="buttonArray"></button>
   <button class="buttonArray"></button>
   <button class="buttonArray"></button>
 </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        const buttonElement = document.getElementById('buttonWrapper');
        buttonElement.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            document.querySelectorAll('#buttonWrapper button').forEach(function (el) {
                el.className = "buttonArray";});
                if (e.target.className === "buttonArray") {
                    e.target.className = "buttonSelect";
                }
                else {
                    e.target.className = "buttonArray";
                }
        });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cg6n5ahd/

What's the easiest way to solve this with my code?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Radio buttons and checkboxes work as select/ deselect. Buttons don't work that way. Use JS to control if a button is clicked for the second time.

Comment: Use the native input checkbox element as what you've described is its intended behavior so that you avoid reinventing the wheel. It can be decorated using the `::before` & `::after` pseudoelements for styling purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found out that the way I wanted to do this was actually not possible at all so I had to completely redo it to this technique without CSS. Deselecting even with radios was pretty awkward too as they aren't really designed to be deselected either except for work arounds like this one.

```js
function deselectRadio(rootElement) {
  if (!rootElement) rootElement = document;
  if (!window.radioChecked) window.radioChecked = {};
  window.radioClick = function(e) {
    const obj = e.target,
      name = obj.name || "unnamed";
    if (e.keyCode) return obj.checked = e.keyCode != 32;
    obj.checked = window.radioChecked[name] != obj;
    window.radioChecked[name] = obj.checked ? obj : null;
  }
  rootElement.querySelectorAll("input[type='radio']").forEach(radio => {
    radio.setAttribute("onclick", "radioClick(event)");
    radio.setAttribute("onkeyup", "radioClick(event)");
  });
}
deselectRadio();
```

```html
<div id="buttonWrapper">
  <input type="radio" name="tabRadio" id="radio1" />
  <input type="radio" name="tabRadio" id="radio2" />
  <input type="radio" name="tabRadio" id="radio3" />
  <input type="radio" name="tabRadio" id="radio4" />
  <input type="radio" name="tabRadio" id="radio5" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const buttonElement = document.getElementById('buttonWrapper');
buttonElement.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  document.querySelectorAll('#buttonWrapper button').forEach(function(el) {
    e.target.className = e.target.className == 'buttonArray' ? 'buttonSelect' : 'buttonArray';
  });
 
});
```

```css
body {
  color: #000;
  background: #eee;
}

.buttonArray {
  border-color: darkgray;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.buttonArray:hover {
  border-color: #a0a0a0;
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
}

.buttonSelect {
  border-color: goldenrod;
  background-color: gold;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#buttonWrapper {
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 1rem;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  z-index: 1;
  background: transparent;
}
```

```html
 <div id="buttonWrapper">
   <button class="buttonArray"></button>
   <button class="buttonArray"></button>
   <button class="buttonArray"></button>
   <button class="buttonArray"></button>
   <button class="buttonArray"></button>
 </div>
```